# Why does this GET for favicon.ico fire and fail if my HTML5 passes validation?

Tags: html, favicon, w3c-validation

I have the following HTML page as a test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Best Title Ever!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Finally, some content.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I test that HTML at the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) it will state :

> Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show.

Even though there are no errors when the page is served from Node's http-server I see (in the console) the following warning or error when the page is retrieved:

```
[2020-10-28T13:10:48.760Z]  "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"
```

You can also see the error in the Chrome or FireFox console which looks like:

FireFox ==> `GET http://127.0.0.1:8003/favicon.ico [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms`

Chrome ==> `Failed to load resource: favicon.ico:1 the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

What is attempting to retrieve that icon?

**Things I've Tried**

I've attempted to retrieve this from:

1. FireFox - 82.0 64-bit
2. Chrome - Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Is this error not correct?

**How Do I Resolve This?**
Is it a requirement that a favicon.ico is always set with*

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

*From https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

**Adding that does indeed resolve the issue** (the failed GET is no longer displayed), even though the png link doesn't even exist.

If it is a requirement then why doesn't the W3 validator warn me to add it?

Is that a bug in the W3 Validator?

Comment: I think what you're seeing is the browser looking for a favicon and not finding it. You can absolutely ignore it without any issue, or you can create a favicon for your site if you so prefer.

Comment: @Aioros That's good to know that I can ignore it, but it is odd that I see the error in the browser and on the HTTP server even though the document validates. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The document has nothing wrong, it's just that most browsers always look for that particular file (and most crawlers look for robots.txt, and most attackers look for wp-admin.php), so you get the 404 logged when they don't find it.